# How to link a pdf

Tags: mkdocs

I tried `[here](adevertising.pdf)` to link a pdf which is in the same folder of my markdown file, but when I click on the link I end up with a 404 page not found error.

How can I create a link that will redirect the user to a pdf storred in the same folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a `/`:

```
[here](/adevertising.pdf)
```