# How to embed a local pdf file in mkdocs generated website on github-pages?

Tags: html, pdf, markdown, github-pages, mkdocs

I have a private repository with some pdf files among others. The content is however, made publicly available using MkDocs (material) and github-pages. I want to embed these locally available pdf files on the website (created with MkDocs). So far I have tried this:

```html
# Method-1
<object data="/path/to/file.pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="/path/to/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>

# Method-2
<a href="/path/to/file.pdf" class="image fit"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></a>
```

The `/path/to/file.pdf`, when shared from Google Drive (made publicly available), works. But, it does not work when I try to show the files kept within the `docs` folder in my github repository.

> **How can I show them from the repository itself (without having to copy and share the files from GDrive)?**

For github pages:

- only the contents of the `docs` folder are pushed to the `gh-pages` branch and then GitHub Pages publishes these contents as the website.

#### Related Material

- Stackoverflow:

  - [*How to link a pdf?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852738/how-to-link-a-pdf)
  - [*Opening PDF in a browser with Github Pages*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745981/opening-pdf-in-a-browser-with-github-pages)
- GitHub Community:

  - [*How to link a pdf which opens a pdf-viewer in GitHub pages?*](https://github.community/t/how-to-link-a-pdf-which-opens-a-pdf-viewer-in-github-pages/10643)

Comment: The link you shared is from a public repo. I have the pdf files in a private repo. Since mkdocs can access images from a private repo, I am hoping to make available pdfs from the private repo as well. Also, a relative path to these pdf files is a better (preferable) option for me. Otherwise, I would resort to using PDF files maintained from a GDrive location.

Comment: Thank you, @KJ.

Comment: Figured it out myself. Will post my answer later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

The main challenge in making the pdf file available on the published site is creating a link that is not broken and actually accesses the file from the repository.

Mkdocs comes with a lot of extensions, that enhance the functionality of the framework. You need to use [`pymdownx.pathconverter`](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/pathconverter/) to address this issue.

### Example

I have blurred out the contents from the screenshot. But you can see how the embedded pdf file looks like.

[image]

Here are the pieces you need to work with.

#### A. Install PyMdown Extension

Along with Other must haves...

```
pip install \
    mkdocs \
    mkdocs-material \
    mkdocs-material-extensions \
    pymdown-extensions
```

#### B. Update `mkdocs.yml`

Add the following to `mkdocs.yml`

```yaml
# Strategy: Use an absolute path
markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.pathconverter:
      base_path: 'YOUR_REPO_NAME' # default: ''
      relative_path: '' # default ''
      absolute: true # default: false
      tags: 'a script img link object embed'
```

A note to the reader: You can also use a relative path with `pymdownx.pathconverter`. For details, please see the documentation. However, for brevity, in case you end up using relative path, this is what your need to do:

1. Set `absolute: false` in the extension settings for `pymdownx.pathconverter`.
2. Use relative path (this should take into account your URL path hierarchy). For instance, if you embed a pdf-file `docs/artifacts/file.pdf` in a markdown file `docs/howto/embedding_pdf.md` and the link to the markdown file looks like `http://localhost:8000/demo_mkdocs_project/howto/embedding-a-pdf-file` (please see the following sections for more context), then the relative path to the file while embedding it, would look like:

```py
"../../artifacts/file.pdf"
```

#### C. Embed PDF file from the repository

Here we will assume the pdf file is located at: `docs/artifacts/file.pdf` and the `docs` folder is located at the root of the repository. In the following code block I embed a pdf in the file `docs/howto/embedding_pdf.md`.

```markdown
<!--- file: docs/howto/embedding_pdf.md --->
{% with pdf_file = "artifacts/file.pdf" %}

{% set solid_filepdf = '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>' %}
{% set empty_filepdf = '<i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i>' %}

## Example: Embedding a PDF file

<object data="{{ pdf_file }}" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="{{ pdf_file }}" type="application/pdf" />
</object>

## Example: Creating a link to a PDF file

<a href="{{ pdf_file }}" class="image fit">{{ solid_filepdf }}</a>

{% endwith %}
```

#### D. Add a link to the page in `mkdocs.yml`

This will create a top-level link `HowTo` and then under that another link `Embedding a PDF file`.

```yaml
# file: mkdocs.yml

nav:
  - Home: index.md
  - HowTo:
    - Embedding a PDF file: howto/embedding_pdf.md
```

These four steps essentially make the pdf file available both on your local server (localhost:8000) and on github pages (in case you are publishing there). The link to the file would then resemble this:

- Local server: `http://localhost:8000/demo_mkdocs_project/artifacts/file.pdf`
- GitHub Pages: `http://githubid.github.io/demo_mkdocs_project/artifacts/file.pdf`

> **Note**:
>
> I assumed the
>
> - Git userid: `githubid`
> - repository name: `demo_mkdocs_project`

### References

1. [PyMdown Extensions Documentation - **PathConverter**](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/pathconverter/)

Comment: Does this example in this answer (i.e. "C") require something like https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs_macros_plugin to enable the jinja2 template functionality? Would be good to update the answer with that additional info if so.

Comment: Yes, I used **Material for MkDocs**, which makes use of the `mkdocs_macros_plugin`.